# When training a convnet, why does last stage of each epoch take so long?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm running some tutorial code for a binary image classification problem. Its a very simple architecture (3 convolution/relu/pooling + fully connected), however the final training step of each epoch takes ~130 seconds, whereas the first 127 take 20s in total. Could anyone explain this and can I somehow speed this up? I'm running on my GPU with 2GB VRAM.

```
rmsprop = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=rmsprop,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

nb_epoch = 30
nb_train_samples = 2048
nb_validation_samples = 832


model.summary()
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

`127/128 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7302 - acc: 0.5266`

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 148, 148, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 74, 74, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 72, 72, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 34, 34, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 18496)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                1183808   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,212,513.0
Trainable params: 1,212,513.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You have `validation_generator` specified, so the network is doing validation. If you omit that argument, then there should be no delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your script saves or validates without declaring this in your ETA-calculation

Comment: It does validate in each epoch, but the example notebook gave runtimes of 40s for the whole thing. Anything I can do or just accept that it will take ages?

Comment: Well something IS going on in the background. There is no intrinsic reason I can come up with why the last step in an epoch should trake longer from a normal training perspective. Usually (in my code) at the end of an epoch I do save the model and/or validate and that might be the explanation. But one would need to check the respective code.